# template-parameter vs type-parameter vs non-type parameter

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

In the C++ Standard in chapter 14 (Templates) it refers to template parameters with several different names, depending on their context.

*non-type parameter*

```
 template<int N>
 class foo {};
```

*template parameter*

```
template<typename T>
class bar {};
```

*type-parameter*

```
 ?????
```

In this quote below, it makes it seem like these are three distinct things, however I can't figure out what *type-parameter* is?

**14.1 Template parameters [temp.param]**

> 9 ... A default template-argument may be specified for any kind of template-parameter **(type, non-type, template)** that is not a template parameter pack (14.5.3). ...

You can see here that it has three distinct names for template parameters.  If *template-parameter* was a generalization of the other two, then why include that in the list above.

In section 14.1.2 it then refers to them as just *type* and *non-type*, and the template-parameter as a generalization.

So what is it? Can someone explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the context you are using this wording, "*template parameters*" are parameters which are class templates. For instance:

```
template<template<typename, typename> class T, typename U, int N>
struct { ... };
```

Here, `T` is a *template parameter*, `U` is a *type parameter*, and `N` is a non-type parameter.

> In section 14.1.2 it then refers to them as just type and non-type, and the template-parameter as a generalization.

Here it is important to disambiguate the use of the word "template". In many contexts, it is just used to indicate that those are parameters "of a template" (as opposed to parameters of a function, for instance). In that case, these categories become (respectively) "*template template parameters*", "*template type parameters*", and "*template non-type parameters*".

Also, in some situations the first category is also considered to define a "non-type parameter", because the arguments which can be provided for it are not *types* (they are templates). Therefore, sometimes you may find the wording "*non-type, non-template parameters*" to refer strictly to the third category (i.e. the category of `N` above).

Also see footnote 136 to Paragraph 14.1/2 of the C++11 Standard:

> Since *template template-parameters* and *template template-arguments* are treated as types for descriptive purposes, the
>   terms *non-type parameter* and *non-type argument* are used to refer to non-type, non-template parameters and arguments.

Answer (score 8):

It's saying that there are three types of *template-parameter*:

1. Type template parameter

   ```
   template<typename T>
   class bar {};
   ```
2. Non-type template parameter

   ```
   template<int N>
   class foo {};
   ```
3. Template template parameter

   ```
   template<template<class> class T>
   class baz {};
   ```

I do however agree that this is badly defined. In the grammar, a *template-parameter* that begins with `template` is one of the possible productions of *type-parameter*.